Visual Studio Code Interactive Python - Show/Copy Jupyter Variables
I am moving from Spyder, and so far I am happy with it.
However, one thing that I haven't been able to solve.
I can click on a list variable and it will open Data Wrangler which is good.
However, any long strings, don't open to reveal the full string in a textbox.
Also, I can't get the right-click copy to work, which I could copy it into a text editor to view.
The other workaround I thought was displaying the variable, but for html it adds it in single quotes and replaces the line breaks with \n which is then not readable.



Hello, if you try to use get_ipython().getoutput('echo $html') , can you get the desired effect?

Thanks, that was returning an error, I think due to the string length. I think I'll need to use pyperclip.copy(html) going forward.

It's also a good option. If this gives the desired result, that's great.
